# scrapy - python question

Tags: python, distributed, scrapy, web-crawler

Maybe not the correct place to post. But, I'm going to try anyway!

I've got a couple of test python parsing scripts that I created. They work enough for me to test what I'm working on.

However, I recently came across the python framework, Scrapy, which is used for web scraping. My app runs in a distributed process, across a testbed of multiple servers. I'm trying to understand scrapy, to see if it provides benefits over what I'm doing.

So, if possible, I'd really like to talk with a few people who are grounded in/or who use scrapy.

Answer (score 7):

A good place to send an email would be their [Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/scrapy-users). There will likely be many users to help answer your general questions.

They also have an [IRC channel](http://irc://irc.freenode.net/scrapy) for more rapid and direct interaction.

Comment: hi jake..

checked on the irc channel.. didn't even think about the google groups though..